# Add item to a generic observablecollection

Tags: c#, generics, observablecollection

I want a method with a generic ObservableCollection return type.
In this method a ObservableCollection will be filled with objects like employees, contracts or holidays, what ever is needed at this moment. So it can be a list of employees, or contracts, or holidays. All are classes with different properties.
Following code gives me the error that Employee can not be converted to T. What else I have to do?

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> getList<T>()
{
    ObservableCollection<T> result = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    Common.Employee employee = new Common.Employee();
    result.Add(employee);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: maybe you can add a constraint at the end of your method signature: `where T : new()` and then in your code you could do: `result.Add(new T())`. It's not clear to me why you are instantiating a *specific* object for the collection in a *generic* method..?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to define an empty interface e.g. `IEntity` and state that `Employee` class implements this interface:

```
interface IEntity
{

}

class Employee : IEntity
{

}
```

Then you should require at the signature method that `T` should implement `IEntity` and change the type you declare for your local variable `employee`:

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> GetList<T>() where T : IEntity
{
    ObservableCollection<T> result = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    IEntity employee = new Common.Employee();
    result.Add(employee);

    return result;
}
```

**Despite the fact** that the above approach would solve the compilation error, I don't get the implementation of `GetList` method. Why in a generic method we have to create an instance of a specific object and then add this to a list and return this list ? What's the purpose for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a generic method, you should not initialize a specific implementation of an object inside of it. A better option would be to have the caller pass a parameter of the generic object type, then add it to the collection.

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> getList<T>(T observableItem)
{
    ObservableCollection<T> result = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    result.Add(observableItem);
    return result;
}
```

Or, you can create a new instance of T within the method.

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> getList<T>() where T : new()
{
    ObservableCollection<T> result = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    T observableItem = new T();

    result.Add(observableItem);
    return result;
}
```